# Multiple constructor calls in *ngFor when clicked on td element Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, constructor, ngfor, jquery-click-event

I have child/parent components, and in parent view in table assign the value and child tag in `td`

Code example:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of pagedItems" (click)="getUserDetails(user,$event)" 
            data-toggle="control-sidebar" id="table-row">
   <td>
      <control-sidebar [user]="userDetails"></control-sidebar>
      {{ user.name }}
   </td>
<tr>
```

and when I clicked on element the child with tag `control-sidebar` constructor is invoked several times instead of just one time.

constructor code in child component:

```
constructor(private http: UserHttpService) {
    if (jQuery.AdminLTE && jQuery.AdminLTE.controlSidebar) {
        jQuery.AdminLTE.controlSidebar.activate();
    }
}
```

...

if I add this condition to `AfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (jQuery.AdminLTE && jQuery.AdminLTE.controlSidebar) {
        jQuery.AdminLTE.controlSidebar.activate();
    }
}
```

this condition used 1 time, but i need to only use constructor

Comment: "constructor code" of what?